# Not able to parse correctly a yaml file with symfony TreeNode

Tags: php, parsing, symfony, yaml, config

I'm trying to do something apparently simple.

I want to parse this yaml structure:

```
  filters:
    filter:
      class: ParentNamespace\MyClassA
    filter:
      class: ParentNamespace\MyClassB
      params:
        customParam: 5
        anotherParam: 1
```

So, i want a required filters node which itself can have 1 or more filter node. Each of then must have a 'class' node and have an optional params array node.

I'm trying with this TreeBuilder but its taking only the second filter, i wonder if is overriding the first one.

I tried with everything and can't get this working.

```
->arrayNode('filters')
    ->isRequired()
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('filter')
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('class')
                    ->isRequired()
                ->end()
                ->arrayNode('params')
                    ->defaultValue(array())
                    ->prototype('variable')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make the `filter` node a prototyped array node. Now it is overriding itself, since an ArrayNode can only have one occurrence:

```
->arrayNode('filters')
    ->isRequired()
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('filter')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('class')
                        ->isRequired()
                    ->end()
                    ->arrayNode('params')
                        ->defaultValue(array())
                        ->prototype('variable')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

---

Besides this, I would suggest you to use something like this instead:

```
filters:
  ParentNamespace\MyClassA: ~
  ParentNamespace\MyClassB:
    params:
      customParam: 5
      anotherParam: 1
```

It's much more friendly and allows you to support XML:

```
->fixXmlConfig('filter')
->children()
    ->arrayNode('filters')
        ->useAttributeAsKey('class')
        ->prototype('array')
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('params')
                    ->defaultValue(array())
                    ->prototype('variable')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

At last, I recommend you to use `requiresAtLeastOneElement()` instead of `isRequired()` to require at least one element.